# altering footer page on drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal 6, my module had this next function which inserted a javascript to the footer of the page, but in Drupal 7, stuff have changed. How can I do this next code in drupal 7?

```
function myfunc_footer()
 {
    if(variable_get('myvar',1) && !drupal_match_path(drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']),  
          'admin/*'))
    {
         if ($somevar = variable_get('somevar',''))
             {
        return '<script src="'.$somevar.'" type="text/javascript"></script>';
         }
         else
             {
        drupal_set_message(t('something is wrong.'));
         }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your code has changed from Drupal 6 to 7...all of the functions are valid and if this worked for Drupal 6 there's no reason it wouldn't work for Drupal 7.

I don't really understand why you're running `drupal_match_path` against a path alias though, you should be running that against the *router* path, not URL path:

```
if(variable_get('myvar',1) && !drupal_match_path($_GET['q'], 'admin/*')) {
```

Try that and see if it fixes your problem, if not could you expand a bit about what error you're getting?

EDIT

Thanks for the update, your second comment below is nearly right, you just need to give the render array a key:

```
function myfunc_page_alter(&$page) { 
  $page['page_bottom']['my_extra_element'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<div><h3> testingthisout</h3> </div>', 
    '#weight' => 25
  ); 
}
```

You don't need to specify `'#type' => 'markup'` as `markup` is the default.

Then make sure your module (the one called `myfunc`) is definitely installed, and clear the caches. You shouldn't have any problems from there

Comment: Hi, there was a change from drupal6 to drupal7. hook_footer() was removed and now I need to use hook_page_build which i named it myfunc_page_build().

Comment: I tried the next code which didn't work: function myfunc_page_build(&$page)
{
  $page['page_bottom']['']= array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div><h3> testingthisout</h3> </div>',
      '#weight' => 25,
      );
  
}

Comment: hook_footer() was removed, $closure became $page_bottom, $page_top added

Comment: I've changed it to what you have said, but nothing was printed to the footer of the page. the module is installed. does the name of that myfunc_page_build is ok ? does the names need to match? where does this function get actually called?

Comment: My bad, the hook function is called [`hook_page_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) so your function should be called `myfunc_page_alter` if your module is called `myfunc`. Make sure to clear the caches once you've changed the name or Drupal won't pick it up

Comment: thanks, ill try that tomorrow, by clearing cache you mean browser cache right?

Comment: No Drupal's caches, go to `admin/config/development/performance` and press the 'Clear all caches' button :-)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I will check it up tomorrow and I will let you know. thank you very much for time and help :-)